# Cannot find symbol - constructor item()

Tags: java, constructor, symbols, default-constructor

Consider this code:

```
// Create a Item oject
item item = new item();
```

Compiler error message:

> Error - Cannot find symbol - Constructor item();

Class `item`:

```
public class item
{
    // Attributes
    private String Itemcode;
    private String Itemname;
    private String Description;
    private String Style;
    private String Finish;
    private float  Unitprice;
    private float  Stock;
    private String Suppliercode;
    private String Suppliername;
    private String Address;

    public item(String ItemcodeIn, String ItemnameIn, String DescriptionIn,
                String StyleIn, String FinishIn, float UnitpriceIn, float StockIn,
                String SuppliercodeIn,
                String SuppliernameIn, String AddressIn)
    {
        Itemcode = ItemcodeIn;
        Itemname = ItemnameIn;
        Description = DescriptionIn;
        Style = StyleIn;
        Finish = FinishIn;
        Unitprice = UnitpriceIn;
        Stock = StockIn;
        Suppliercode = SuppliercodeIn;
        Suppliername = SuppliernameIn;
        Address = AddressIn;
    }
```

And this code is then followed by all of the setter/getter methods for the attributes.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Side Note: In Java, it's customary to use `PascalCase` for class names and `camelCase` for variable names. So, if you followed the convention, your class name would be `Item` and your variable names would be `itemCodeIn`, `itemNameIn`, `item`, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you create a parameterized constructor, the default constructor is removed unless you create your own.

Hence you have to explicitly create a default constructor as below:

```
public Item() {}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to add a default constructor:

```
public item() {
   // any initialization you need here
}
```

You should also rename your class to `Item` (capital `I`) per best practices, and your fields should begin with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Item` class only has 1 constructor:

```
public item(String ItemcodeIn, String ItemnameIn, String DescriptionIn, 
     String StyleIn, String FinishIn, float UnitpriceIn, float StockIn, 
     String SuppliercodeIn, String SuppliernameIn, String AddressIn)
```

Though you're trying to access it through `new Item();` This constructor does not exist since you have over-ridden it with a parametrized one.

You should either provide those arguments when creating your `Item` or create another, generic constructor:

```
public Item() {
    // Some code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you do not write any constructor , default constructor is by default available within the class. But, if you define  write a parametrized constructor within any class, then only that parametrized constructor is available. In such a case, you will have to explicitly define a default constructor.